# User Logout redirect using this.props.history.push('/') does not redirect to desired page

Tags: reactjs, firebase

After a user logouts, I'd like the page to navigate back to my home screen, `'/'`. I am trying to use `this.props.history.push('/')` however, the page remains on the current profile page, `/profile#signout` and reads the error `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`.

Here is my code for my logOutUser() function. I am using Firebase for my logout.

```
logOutUser(){
  var tempname = login.getUser();
  firebase
  .auth()
  .signOut()
  .then(function() {
    alert("Goodbye " + tempname + "!");
    this.props.history.push('/');
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    alert(error.message);
  });
}
```

Which is called by my navClicked() function. This function checks to see which nav portion the user is currently in and returns the needed information to the render portion:

```
navClicked(name) {
     if(name === "signout"){
       return(
         <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.logOutUser()}>
           Sign Outed
         </button>
       )
     }
 }
```

and Finally here is my render portion. I am using react-bootstrap cards and check to see which nav is clicked on the profile card.

```
render(){
        const length = window.location.href.length;
        const current = window.location.href.slice(30, length);
        return(
        <Card className = "cardosettings" style={{ width: '60rem', height: '35rem'}}>
          <Card.Header className = 'header0'>
            <Nav variant="tabs" defaultActiveKey="#profile">
                <Nav.Item >
                    <Nav.Link className = 'linka' href="#profile">Edit Profile</Nav.Link>
                </Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Link className = 'linka' href="#settings">Account Settings</Nav.Link>
                </Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Link className = 'linka' href="#signout">Sign Out</Nav.Link>
                </Nav.Item>
            </Nav>
        </Card.Header>
            <ListGroup variant="flush">
              {this.navClicked(current)}
            </ListGroup>
          </Card>
        )
    }
```

Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `logOutUser` intended to be different from `logOutcurrentUser`? Also, is `logOutUser` being invoked and properly handling at the signout? Any errors?

Comment: Shoot my bad, forgot to edit the names. There should only be logOutUser! And yes I get the error: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing logoutUser and your callback to arrow functions to avoid binding issues with `this`:

```
logOutUser = () => {
  var tempname = login.getUser();
  firebase
  .auth()
  .signOut()
  .then(() => {
    alert("Goodbye " + tempname + "!");
    this.props.history.push('/');
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    alert(error.message);
  });
}
```

In addition, if you are dealing with a child component that may not have acccess to history by default, wrap your component with `withRouter` from `router-router-dom`.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
export default withRouter(YourComponent);
```

Comment: That makes sense! However, now I receive the error message "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". Any ideas?